# Floating li elements: Why do they cover up the parent div element?

Tags: css, html

Why does the yellow stripe (#header) disappear when I set "#header ul li" to **float left;** ?
Having set a fixed size for "#header ul li", I would expect the li elements to sit side-by-side and not more. 3 * 100px is not wide enough to cover #header which streches horizontally over the whole page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#header {
    background: yellow;
}
#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#header ul li {
    background: pink;
    width: 100px;
    float: left; // <--- here!
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>

</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend reading http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/ for an quick image demonstrating the problem of float containment, and for a discussion of good CSS fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Because floating elements are taken [out of the content flow:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box of the float.

You'll have to use `<div style="clear:left;"></div>` in order to correct this:

```
<div id="header">
<ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are better clears without adding unnecessary markup (`<div style="clear: left;"></div>`). See http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/

Answer (score 0):

When floating child elements you need to set `overflow:auto;` on the parent to have it expand to cover their width and height:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zbkv9/)**

```
#header {
  background: yellow;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: While `overflow` can be used for clearing floats in many situations, be aware that it isn't a good choice if you actually do want some content to overflow (ie. drop menus).

Comment: @cimmanon - I didn't set the overflow to hidden, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're taking the li's out of the document flow by floating them, you'll have to either set an explicit height on your ul or use a clear div to "push" the height of the #header past the ul.

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.clear {clear:both;}
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QHrwZ/1/